# How many numbers of 6 digits, that can be formed with digits 2,3,9. And also divided by 6?

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers of 6 digits, that can be formed with digits 2,3,9. And also divided by 6?
I was trying first when all are 9 but it have to have more restrictions what are they?

Comment: Closely related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620247/how-many-numbers-of-6-digits-that-can-be-formed-with-digits-2-3-9-and-also-div) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620609/combinatorics-question-i-need-help-with).

Comment: @user7777777 why do ask same question thrice???

Comment: @Unknown: Because third time's the charm ! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since it is devieded by 6 it must be of the form XXXXX2 and also either (a) all of X's are 2 or (b) two of them must be 2 and the others can be 3 or 9.

For case (b) we have
$$C(5,2)=\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$$

And for all cases of 3 and 9 we have: 2*2*2=8

Thus for both cases (a) and (b)  $$1+10\cdot8=81$$

Comment: *81 @Farshad Nahangi How can I see that two of them must be 2?

Comment: @user7777777 Since it is devided by 3 so with out 2's you can not obtain a sum of digits which is devided by 3. Recall that a number is devided by 3 only when sum of its digits is devided by 3

Comment: $1+10\cdot 8=81$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $S(n)$ be the digit sum of $n$ in the decimal system.

$n$ is a multiple of $6$ $\iff$ "the rightmost digit is even" and "$S(n)$ is a multiple of $3$."

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. A number is divisible by $6$ if and only if it is divisible by both $2$ and $3$
2. A number is divisible by $2$ if and only if it's last digit is even.
3. A number is divisible by $3$ if and on if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.

2+3 imply put strong restrictions on the number of $2$'s in the numbers you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Apparently all these numbers are even, and hence they are of the form:
$xxxxx2$. Also the sum of the digits should be divisible by $3$, and as $3$ and $9$ are divisible by $3$, while $2$ is not, then there should another two or another five incidents of two.