# How many $6$ digit numbers from the digits $(2,3,9)$ divide by $3$? How many $6$ digit numbers from the digits $(2,3,9)$ divide by $6$?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

> How many $6$ digit numbers from the digits $(2,3,9)$ divide by $3$.
> and another question is the same but divides by $6$.

Comment: Duplicate of [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620309/how-many-numbers-of-6-digits-that-can-be-formed-with-digits-2-3-9-and-also-div) two [posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620247/how-many-numbers-of-6-digits-that-can-be-formed-with-digits-2-3-9-and-also-div).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Divisible by three: the sum of its digits is divisible by three, so $2$ appears zero, three or six times. If it is divisible by six, it is divisible by three and is even, so two is in its ending. But $2$ needs to appear zero, three or six times to be divisible by three, so we need to put $2$ more two or five times.